# How to wait until all of a series of nested CompletableFutures are done?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have an Augmented Reality application where `ARObject` is a POJO:

```
  class ARObject {
    CompletableFuture<Texture> texture;
    CompletableFuture<Material> material;
    ModelRenderable renderable;

    void setTexture(CompletableFuture<Texture> texture) {
      this.texture = texture;
    }

    CompletableFuture<Texture> getTexture() {
      return texture;
    }

    void setMaterial(CompletableFuture<Material> material) {
      this.material = material;
    }

    CompletableFuture<Material> getMaterial() {
      return material;
    }
  }
```

The scene is composed in real-time. During that procedure the `Texture` objects need to be built and then the `Material` objects based on the `Texture` objects. Once the `Material` is ready, then the `ShapeFactory` can be used to spawn the actual AR objects (as a form `Renderable`). That means that the build logic contains two `CompletableFuture`s nested into each other for each AR object:

```
for (ARObject arObject : arObjects) {
  Texture.Builder textureBuilder = Texture.builder();
  textureBuilder.setSource(context, arObject.resourceId);
  CompletableFuture<Texture> texturePromise = textureBuilder.build();  // Future #1
  arObject.setTexture(texturePromise);
  texturePromise.thenAccept(texture -> {
    CompletableFuture<Material> materialPromise =
            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(context, texture);  // Future #2
    arObject.setMaterial(materialPromise);
  });
}
```

One way to complete the scene build is to wait until all of the `CompletableFuture`s are done, and then the `ShapeFactory` step can come.

I tried to use `.get()` on the `Future`s, but that would not just completely butcher the parallelism offered by the async calls, but it did also lock up the app because I assume it caused the wait on the UI thread.

```
Arrays.stream(arObjectList).forEach(a -> {
  try {
    a.getTexture().get();
  } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Texture CompletableFuture waiting problem " + e.toString());
  }
});
Arrays.stream(arObjectList).forEach(a -> {
  try {
    a.getMaterial().get();
  } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Material CompletableFuture waiting problem " + e.toString());
  }
});
```

I broke the build procedure up to several functions which call each other in a call chain. The chain is the following:

1. `populateScene`
2. `afterTexturesLoaded`
3. `afterTexturesSet`
4. `waitForMaterials`
5. `afterMaterialsLoaded`

```
  private void afterMaterialsLoaded() {
    // Step 3: composing scene objects
    // Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    for (ARObject arObject : arObjectList) {
      try {
        Material textureMaterial = arObject.getMaterial().get();

        RunnableShapeBuilder shapeBuilder = new RunnableShapeBuilder(arObject, this, textureMaterial);
        mainHandler.post(shapeBuilder);
      }
      catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Scene populating exception " + e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  private Long waitForMaterials() {
    while (!Stream.of(arObjectList).allMatch(arObject -> arObject.getMaterial() != null)) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
    return 0L;
  }

  private void afterTexturesSet() {
    boolean materialsDone = Stream.of(arObjectList).allMatch(arObject -> arObject.getMaterial() != null && arObject.getMaterial().isDone());
    // If any of the materials are not loaded, then recurse until all are loaded.
    if (!materialsDone) {
      CompletableFuture<Texture>[] materialPromises =
        Stream.of(arObjectList).map(ARObject::getMaterial).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

      CompletableFuture.allOf(materialPromises)
        .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> afterMaterialsLoaded())
        .exceptionally(
          throwable -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception building scene", throwable);
            return null;
          });
    } else {
      afterMaterialsLoaded();
    }
  }

  private void afterTexturesLoaded() {
    // Step 2: material loading
    CompletableFuture materialsSetPromise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::waitForMaterials);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(materialsSetPromise)
      .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> afterTexturesSet())
      .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Log.e(TAG, "Exception building scene", throwable);
          return null;
        });
  }

  /**
   * Called when the AugmentedImage is detected and should be rendered. A Sceneform node tree is
   * created based on an Anchor created from the image.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
  void populateScene() {
    // Step 1: texture loading
    boolean texturesDone = Stream.of(arObjectList).allMatch(arObject -> arObject.getTexture() != null && arObject.getTexture().isDone());
    // If any of the textures are not loaded, then recurse until all are loaded.
    if (!texturesDone) {
      CompletableFuture<Texture>[] texturePromises =
        Stream.of(arObjectList).map(ARObject::getTexture).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

      CompletableFuture.allOf(texturePromises)
        .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> afterTexturesLoaded())
        .exceptionally(
          throwable -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception building scene", throwable);
            return null;
          });
    } else {
      afterTexturesLoaded();
    }
  }
```

There are several problem with this. First: it still kind of botches the asynchronous nature. In an ideal situation a corresponding material texture pair would be independently loaded and generated from the other pairs. In this latest version there are many meeting points in the execution flow, which does not correspond to the ideal independent scenario. Second: I even could not avoid the `waitForMaterials` step where I have ugly `Thread.sleep()`. Third: the code still fails overall, because at the last step when it comes to finally build the shapes from the loaded textures and materials, I'm gifted with an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from the UI thread.`. Because of this I put in another twist: `RunnableShapeBuilder`. With that there's no exception, but still nothing is shown on the scene, while the code get even more complicated.

```
  class RunnableShapeBuilder implements Runnable {
    ARObject arObject;
    AnchorNode parentNode;
    Material textureMaterial;

    RunnableShapeBuilder(ARObject arObject, AnchorNode parentNode, Material textureMaterial) {
      this.arObject = arObject;
      this.parentNode = parentNode;
      this.textureMaterial = textureMaterial;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      arObject.renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
        new Vector3(0.5f, 1, 0.01f),
        new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        textureMaterial
      );
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since within `if(!texturesDone) { … }` you are scheduling another call to the same method, there is no reason to proceed with the current method execution. In other words, just add a `return;` at the end, `if(!texturesDone) { /* schedule the call */ return; }`.

Comment: @Holger I realize that a while ago, the code is changed, I'll update my answer

Comment: I made a big reorganization of the question, maybe more coming. Hopefully the problem is somewhat more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: I do not have to wait for these nested `CompletableFuture`s. While my scenario got more complex I assumed I'd have to wait until construction of the 3D Material and Texture is complete. The problem was in an off-topic place: although I set the AR object's anchor. The AR Object's anchor is derived from the hit test, and I'd need to set the parent of the anchor to the AR Scene. This last step was lost during some refactorings, and nothing warns you if this happens, just nothing show up on the AR Scene.

Focusing on the question itself: I highly disadvise to try to wait on any because it'll lead to pain and suffering only. Seek for a different alley of solution.